# RDS Upgrade Fails despite prepatchcompatibility showing no errors

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, upgrade, amazon-rds

We are looking to upgrade our RDS Mysql From 5.7 to 8.0.11.  When try to modify and upgrade the instance from AWS UI we get a

> Database instance is in a state that cannot be upgraded: PreUpgrade checks failed: RDS detected Incompatibilities upgrading to MySQL 8.0.15. More details can be found in the PrePatchCompatibility.log file, accessible in the 'logs' section below.

error in the recent events area but when we download the PrePatchCompatibility.log the only messages we see are

> 3) Usage of utf8mb3 charset
>       The following objects use the utf8mb3 character set. It is recommended to convert them to use utf8mb4 instead, for improved Unicode support.
>       More Information:
>           https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

schema.table.column - column's default character set: utf8

I've looked this message up and the compatibility issues associated with it and this is supposed to be a warning.  The bottom of the log shows

Errors: 0
Database Objects Affected: 261

From everything I've Read this should work.

Has anyone successfully upgraded from mysql 5.7 to 8.0 in aws RDS?  Would I actually have to change all of my columns from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4 or is there something else going on?

Comment: Having the same problem when trying 5.7 -> 8.0.15 upgrade. There are no issues/errors stated in PrePatchCompatibility.log, yet unable to upgrade it. It is worth to mention we managed to upgrade replica of the same database like a month ago, which means Amazon probably shadow-changed something meanwhile. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem, impossible to upgrade mysql version from 5.7 to 8.0.
`Usage of db objects with names conflicting with reserved keywords in 8.0` but it does not trigger any error because it's possible to keep those names if we use quotes arround it, which is the case.
I'm looking for a way to bypass the PrePatchCompatibility but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Anybody checked this with AWS support team?

Comment: I checked with AWS support team. As per them, this is an existing issue with AWS RDS and they will rollout a patch soon

Comment: So I posted to aws tech support and after the first reply tried to convince me that the warnings in the Preupgrade Compatibility Log were actually errors they seem to finally admit it was a bug on their end but they were very noncommittal on when it would get fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem. A few months ago we successfully upgraded mysql 5.7 -> 8.0.15 on our dev RDS and now we want to do the same for our prod RDS. This fails because of the same error. Please post updates from Amazon here! @RajatGoel

Comment: Hey folks, RDS MySQL Engineer here. This post was sent to us by an RDS customer, so I thought it would be interesting to chime in and provide you some visibility about this issue. Our team is aware of this issue, and a patch deployment was scheduled to address it. This fix will be transparent to all of our RDS MySQL customers, and will require no additional action from your side once it is released. I would like apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you. Best regards, Your friends from the RDS MySQL team.

Comment: (Continuing...)I would like to reiterate that we appreciate you bringing this issue to our attention, we have listened :) With that said this may be a good time to remind you that our team is constantly monitoring our AWS Official channels such as @aws (Twitter), AWS RDS MySQL Forums (forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=60) and our support tickets of course. We recommend you using these channels if you are looking for a faster response from us.

Comment: Hello guys, I don't have the exact issue but something similar I thought I want to ask.  "mysql - schema's default character set: utf8" I'm not allowed to change this though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After contacting AWS support team, they disabled pre-upgrade checks for our instance. After which we were able to upgrade successfully from 5.7 to 8.0.

They have informed that AWS has a bug and patch for that is ready and will be released soon. Though they didn't provide any ETA for the same. But in case you are in hurry, you can contact them ask for the private patch (or disabling pre-upgrade checks in this case).

Answer (score 2):

RDS MySQL Engineer here.

This post was sent to us by an RDS customer, so I thought it would be interesting to chime in and provide you some visibility about this issue. Our team is aware of this issue, and a patch deployment was scheduled to address it. This fix will be transparent to all of our RDS MySQL customers, and will require no additional action from your side once it is released.

I would like apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you and reiterate that we appreciate you bringing this issue to our attention, we have listened :)

With that said this may be a good time to remind you that our team is constantly monitoring our AWS Official channels such as @aws (Twitter), AWS RDS MySQL Forums (forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=60) and our support tickets of course.

We recommend you using these channels if you are looking for a faster response from us.

Best regards, Your friends from the RDS MySQL team.

Comment: It is 2023 and this has still not been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and the problem was due to a corrupt view, but the upgrade to MySQL 8.x worked after I deleted it (saving its create syntax beforehand via `SHOW CREATE VIEW my_view;`).

I wish I had saved the error that Sequel Ace (macOS) reported, but it was something along the lines of user@localhost not being able to see a view or table.

The culprit was that the view referred to tables and columns which had been renamed some months ago by prior database migrations. So maybe RDS wasn't able to create a SQL dump to restore after the upgrade. I applied the `CREATE VIEW my_view as <query>` after the upgrade, and we proceeded as normal.